# How do I view the properties of a DOM object in Chrome Developer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I want to examine the properties of a DOM object in Google Chrome Web Developer Tools, so I called `console.debug();` with a DOM element as a parameter:

HTML:

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Star_Spangled_Banner_instrumental.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Javascript:

```
console.debug(document.getElementsByTagName('source')[0]);​
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PkGj4/)

However, the Chrome console just displays the HTML of the element upon the call to `console.debug();` and does not reveal any javascript properties of the DOM node object.

How do I view the properties of a DOM object in Chrome Developer? I'm using a Mac.
​

Comment: Have you tried `console.dir($$('source')[0]);`?

Comment: @DCoder you have an error in your code... extra `$` returns: `TypeError: string is not a function` If you remove that character `console.dir($('source')[0]);` will return properties if found

Comment: @Chris22: are you using Chrome? `$$` is a built-in function in the Google Chrome Developer Tools: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#selector_1 . If you are using a different browser or some JS library that redefines `$$` for its own purposes, naturally my suggestion won't work.

Comment: @DCoder, I am using Chrome.  I just copied and pasted your code in the console and got the error. I'm not aware of the variable `$$` being defined in a script somewhere, but that could be the case.  Not trying to start an argument here, just posted the error as I saw it.  Different use cases should be applied, I suppose, as others may get the same error.  But your answer seemed elegant enough and I wondered why it wasn't upvoted.

Comment: @Chris22: that's odd, I have tested on two different Chrome installations and got the expected result. If you suspect `$$` is the problem, you can try `console.dir(document.querySelector('source'))` or some similar approach, without using `$$`.

Comment: @DCoder not sure how much in-depth you want to go with this, :)  I'm using Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 and I am getting the TypeError as listed above. It could be a result of the use case you describe -- another resource redefining `$$` variable.  It's not the latest version, but that's the one my employer has us using for testing outside our network on a VM.

Comment: @Chris22: what do you get if you do `$$.toString()` ? The Dev Tools builtin produces `"function $$(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }"`.

Comment: console.dir is exactly what I was looking for. That should have been the accepted answer. I didn't need $$ though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is add attributes tag to the end.  This will return an array of the attributes.  You may need the JavaScript Kit to actually do this, but then you can just have a loop to go through the attributes no matter how many there are.

```
sourceAttributes = document.getElementsByTagName('source')[0].attributes
for(int i=0; i<sourceAttributes.length; i++) {
    console.debug(sourceAttributes[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

In Chrome you should use the `dir` method:

```
console.dir(document.getElementsByTagName('source')[0]);​
```

Or for the current inspected/highlighted element:

```
console.dir($0);​
```

This will give you a result like so:

[image]

Comment: How do you access those attributes?

Comment: You need only navigate to the console tab in dev tools.

Comment: You can use console.dir($0), where $0 is the currently selected DOM node

Answer (score 1):

The **[HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) properties** (stuff like `scrollTop` or `clientHeight`, well beyond CSS properties) are under the elements tab.

(this tab can be very far right within the order of tabs, thus hiding in the `»` with the “more” tabs. You can change the DevTools Tab-Order by dragging them further left.)

[image]

The option on right-click to „add property path to watch“ (then showing up in the general sources tab) is sadly not working, because only the property name gets copied there, no means to select the HTML element [(not quite as advertised)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/devtools#watch).

**Thus you need to manually enter a selection mechanism and the property there, like:**

```
document.getElementById('123').scrollTop
document.getElementsByTagName('scrollbox')[0]
etc…
```

[image]