# Viewing DOM Elements as Objects in Chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

Is it possible using Chrome's debugger (or another debugging tool) to view DOM Elements as objects?

That is, if I create a regular object in Chrome's console, I'm able to inspect its elements.

```
> o = {}
  - Object
    - __proto__
      - __defineGetter__
      - etc
```

However, if I create a new DOM element, the debugger displays its HTML contents.

```
> p = document.createElement('p')
  <p></p>
```

I'd like to view the variable `p` as an object.  Instead of seeing `<p></p>`, I'd like to see it's properties (as you do when looking at `o` above)

Is this possible in the debugger?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I view the properties of a DOM object in Chrome Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380602/how-do-i-view-the-properties-of-a-dom-object-in-chrome-developer)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe `console.dir()` is what you are after.

```
> p = document.createElement('p')
    <p></p>
> console.dir(p)
    - HTMLDivElement
        align: ""
        ...
```

Image below is from [Google Chrome Console Tools docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)

[image: Showing console.dir]