# Why doesn't Chrome show the properties and methods of the document object in the console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Correct me if I am wrong:

I know that `document` is an object inside `window` (the global object) and is also called the Document Object Model which contains all the functionalities required to manipulate itself.

However, when I open the console and type `window.document`, the value returned is an object that does not contain any functions or properties.

It returns `#document` (I don't understand meaning of the `#` sign) and when I expand it, it only contains the HTML elements with no functions or properties. But when I type `document.`, a list of suggestions of all the available methods appears.

[image: screenshot of browser console showing available methods on the document object]

So why is it that when I type `window.document` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it does not return the DOM with all the functions and properties?

Comment: You're only seeing what the console wants you to see. If you type `window.document.` (note the final period) you should still get hints about the available properties/functions just as you do with `document.` If you just type `document` and press enter you will get the same result as you do for `window.document`

Comment: @phuzi are you suggesting that the document object is a an exception and this is done on purpose and im not missing anything ?

Comment: It's not an exception this the default with any DOM node/element. Yes, it's done on purpose

Comment: @phuzi okey, do you have any reference for further reading ?

Comment: MDN is a great reference/starting point for a lot of JavaScript,HTML,CSS although I don't really have a good reference for the console behaviour (doesn't mean there isn't one though)

Comment: "why when i type `window.document` and press enter; it does not return the dom with all the functions and properties?" Because you're evaluating a JS expression that is the HTML element. So there's no autocomplete (a browser-specific behavior) involved in that. When you add the period, it's no longer a valid JS expression and browsers will hint how to complete the expression by selecting a property on the object. I'm not quite sure why you find this behavior surprising. The returned value _does_ have those funcs and props, just save it in a variable, then type the var name and a `.` to see.

Comment: @ggorlen "Because you're evaluating a JS expression that is the HTML element. ". im evaluation the dom not an html element.

Comment: What's the difference? The DOM (document object model) is a collection of objects that represent the HTML structure. They're HTML elements or DOM nodes. I think you're missing the point here--it doesn't actually matter whether it's related to the DOM at all, it's just an object with a property that's either a valid expression or a partial expression. When it's the latter, browsers typically offer autocomplete. When it's the former, it will evaluate the expression and return the result.

Comment: @ggorlen but the DOM is not an HTML element itself so when i call the window.document it is as if the expression evaluates to window.document.firstChild why is that? why it doesn't evaluate to an object that has first child as a property.

Comment: I don't see that behavior on this page on Chrome. If you type `a = document` then type `a.` to enable autocomplete, you'll see `firstChild` is there pointing to `<!DOCTYPE html>` along with everything else you'd see if you just typed `document.` without an assignment. In other words, the assignment is totally superfluous and nothing magic happens. I think we have terminology confusion: the [DOM is an API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM), not an object `document`, which is the root of the HTML node tree.

Comment: @ggorlen what i meant the expected result is not the firstChild, the expected result is printing all the object properties and functions

Comment: I think we're going in circles here. I aready explained the behavior and why that doesn't happen. Why should an object display all the properties and functions? Autocomplete only happens when you have an incomplete expression. I've written this a few times already so I think I'll step aside and let someone else who understands what you're asking help out.

Comment: @ggorlen im not talking about autocomplete though i said then i press enter, the returned value is not the complete object it is just the firstChild

Comment: Like I said, I'm not seeing that behavior. When I type `document` and press enter, I see `#document`. When I type `document.firstChild` and press enter, I see `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Those are two different things.

Comment: let me show an example. you can type `"some string"` in console and it'd not list it's members. but if you type `"some string".` it shows what you can do. (disclaimer: I did't read through all comments carefully)

Comment: @ggorlen type window.document and press enter and screenshot it please, if it returns a complete object with all the available properties then this is a browser specific issue, as you can see in my post, i screenshot my answer and it returns  #document and when i expand it there are no functions or properties such getElementById

Comment: @ggorlen I think you may mistake me as OP :P.

Comment: @appleapple Oh, sorry.

Comment: @ezio I see the same thing as your screenshot. As I said, this is unsurprising and normal behavior as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ggorlen great now that you do know that this isn't about autocomplete, why would the returned value does not contain all the details about the document such as all the avilable functions and properties?

Comment: I've already been over this multiple times. The return value _does have all of the functions and properties_! It's literally the _exact same object_. Type `a = document` and then type `a.` and you'll see all of the functions and properties. I think you're confused by the way Chrome prints DOM nodes, the `#document` and `<!DOCTYPE html>` formatting. This is just a browser-specific representation of the object, not the actual returned object.

Comment: @ggorlen "The return value does have the functions and properties! It's literally the exact same object", why not show them when i press enter after typing window.document? and is document a dom node? isn't document the DOM!

Comment: Lol. We keep going in circles and making no progress. Please just re-read all of my posts... I've already answered those questions multiple times. "Why not show them..." because Chrome only shows the functions and properties when it's autocompleting but not when you press enter or if you have a valid JS expression that you have typed but not yet pressed enter. It displays objects in its own format that usually doesn't show properties or functions, especially for DOM nodes.

Comment: i will, so far @phuzi answer makes sense

Comment: Phuzi has said the same thing as me.

Comment: @ggorlen if he did, then he gave a concise more clear answer for me, no offense, but thank you for your effort

Comment: @ggorlen if you have read carefully then you would have noticed that i asked for a reference and that is what is missing, his answer makes sense so far but it is not a final answer, so there is still a possibility where his answer is wrong. there is still some confusion that needs to be resolved.

Comment: I think part of the confusion is this: you may think that the thing that Chrome prints that starts with the `#document` is somehow supposed to be the complete object--"the value returned". This `#document` thing with the dropdown arrow next to it is not the value returned. It's a _browser-specific representation of the value (an object) returned_. The actual, programmatic value/object returned has all of the properties you expect (as my `a = document` demo above demonstrates), but the browser-specific representation does not show them by design. Does this make sense?

Comment: Maybe [How do I view the properties of a DOM object in Chrome Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380602/how-do-i-view-the-properties-of-a-dom-object-in-chrome-developer) and [Viewing DOM Elements as Objects in Chrome debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145199/viewing-dom-elements-as-objects-in-chrome-debugger) are relevant.

Comment: @ggorlen your link answered the question, when i use console.dir(document) it shows the complete object, console.log automatically recognize document as something that should be represented as html and returns the approprite node. thank you

Comment: Yes. Glad we made it there. Yes, `console.log()` formats objects different than they actually are.

Comment: @ggorlen thank you so much i appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that `document` is an object inside `window` (the global object) and is also called the Document Object Model which contains all the functionalities required to manipulate itself.

My understanding is that the Document Object Model is a [broader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM) than just the [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) object, which is "the entry point to the page's content" according to MDN.

> However, when I open the console and type `window.document`, the value returned is an object that does not contain any functions or properties.

That's not true. The value returned *does* have all of the functions and properties of `document`; in fact, it's the exact `document` object. You're probably confusing the browser-specific representation shown in your screenshot starting with `#document` with the actual return value.

You can prove this to yourself with an assignment: `foo = document`. Then type `foo.` on the next line and the exact same autocomplete will appear that shows when you type `document.` directly, because `foo` is just an alias of `document`. You can call `foo.querySelector("p")` and it'll work just fine. If you type `foo` or `document` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you'll see the abbreviated `#document` representation.

In Firefox 102.0.1, the same code (typing `document` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) shows something else:

[image: screenshot of firefox console showing all methods and properties of the document object]

Even though it looks different, all of the programmatic logic you might perform on the returned value will work just the same as Chrome (notwithstanding the normal browser-specific implementation differences of the ECMAScript spec).

> I don't understand the meaning of the `#` sign

The `#` is a Chrome-specific way of denoting the element as a "virtual" element that you can't select. It's used in the element tree and for frames and [shadow roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Components#Shadow_DOM). As you can see from the Firefox screenshot above, no `#` appears.

> and when I expand it, it only contains the HTML elements with no functions or properties. But when I type `document.`, a list of suggestions of all the available methods appears.

For whatever reason, Chrome has decided that showing the HTML tree is a more useful representation of a DOM object for `console.log` rather than the properties and methods of the object. (`console.log` is automatically invoked on whatever expression you run in the console)

To see the object displayed in a similar format as the Firefox screenshot above, use `console.dir(document)`. This seems to be more like what you were expecting, showing that the return value indeed has all of the properties and methods of `document`.

Don't confuse how browsers choose to display information in `console.log()` with what the variables and objects actually represent in the program. These are two totally different things, and browsers often elide many properties from things that are logged, present them as very different from the typical JSON representation you might expect, or [live-update the logged object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/how-can-i-make-console-log-show-the-current-state-of-an-object), leading to confusion.

See [What does a key value pair inside the square brackets [] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56190829/what-does-a-key-value-pair-inside-the-square-brackets-mean/56190909#56190909) for a further dive into the [implementation-defined nature of logging](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#object-formats):

> An object with generic JavaScript object formatting is a potentially expandable representation of a generic JavaScript object. An object with optimally useful formatting is an implementation-specific, potentially-interactive representation of an object judged to be maximally useful and informative.

<sub>Used in this post: Chrome 103.0.5060.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)</sub>

Comment: The nodeName `#document` is as per spec - https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-nodename